# Как сделать фон (angular-material, flexbox)?

Tags: css, angularjs

прошу прощения, что ставлю тег angular, но, может, кто работал с angular-material

Хочу сделать список имен, разбитый на столбики с помощью flexbox

Пример 1

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZUKHlC?p=preview

Так всё работает. Но если я оборачиваю всё в

```
 div layout="row"
```

то происходит следующее

Пример 2

http://plnkr.co/edit/e86jtj?p=preview

А мне необходимо делать

```
layout="row" в ui-view
```

, чтобы фон на остальных страницах был 100%
Как это победить?

Answer (score 2):

так как после добавления `layout="row"` к элементу с атрибутом `ui-view` див, который отвечает за показ внутренней строки становится вложенным, то его ширина считается по содержимому. Чтобы его растянуть на ширину контейнера, нужно добавить  свойство

```
flex-grow:1
```

Пример с inline-стилем, можно просто добавить необходимую строчку в класс:

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" layout="row" style="flex-grow:1" class="mainPallete">
    <div layout="column" layout-wrap style="max-height :calc(100vh); height: 100%">
      <p flex="20" ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy:'name'" style="padding-left: 20vh;" >{{item.name}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/B8qtV4Bo3MZqGf89m4B9?p=preview)

[Хорошее руководство по *display:flex*](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Дай вам Бог здоровья, мил человек! Огромное спасибо за объяснение и ссылку.